# .NET Core on Linux - Marshal structures

Tags: c++, linux, .net-core, pinvoke, marshalling

I have a .NET Core console app that calls some functions from C++ library. The function I'm trying to call simpty taken in some `settings` and outputs the result into `result`.

C++:

```
struct settings
{
    char* input_path;
    char* first_file;
    char* second_file;
    char* mask;
    char* log_path;
    int count_accepted;
    double confidence;
    char* device;
};

struct result
{
    int count;
    foo* foos;
    bool is_preprocessed;
    double duration;
};

bool process_input(const settings& settings, result* result);
```

C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Settings
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string input_path;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string first_file;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string second_file;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string mask;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string log_path;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int count_accepted;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)]
    public double confidence;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string device;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Result
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int count;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysInt)]
    public IntPtr foos;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
    public bool is_preprocessed;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)]
    public double duration;
}

[DllImport("myLib", EntryPoint = "process_input", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
[return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
public static extern bool ProcessInput(Settings settings, out Result result);
```

This all works well on Windows but does not work on Linux. When I print the settings on a C++ side (from `process_input`), I get completely different values in int and double properties, and a Segmentation Fault when try to access char* property.

I also tried to call this library from C++ code (Windows and Linux) and it works as expected. As I understand, this is a marshaling problem, but I can't pinpoint it myself. I'm a C# developer and don't have much experience with C++ or PInvoke or Linux.

I work with Windows 10 (x64) and Ubuntu 16.04 (x64).

Comment: Start with some debugging code. Check the offsets of the struct in both C# and C++. Do they match?

Comment: Yes, the offsets match.

Comment: Now check whether the data is being transferred correctly

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: I tried to pass a struct with a single int property but got segfault again.

Comment: I think the problem is solved. Looks like the app was using wrong .so. I deleted the library and restarted the system. Then rebuilt everything and it started working.

Comment: Okay, what actually caused the error to go away is that I changed the function signature from `bool process_input(const settings& settings, result* result)` to `bool process_input(settings settings, result* result)`. Why is this a problem on Linux but not on Windows?

Comment: It's a problem on Windows too but you are getting lucky. You wouldn't get the right data on Windows.

Comment: But I do get the right data on Windows. The app has been running on Windows for some time with no problem. How so? What is wrong with passing a struct as const ref in this case?

Comment: On WIndows I would have expected the C# to pass the struct by value on the stack. But perhaps the calling convention is not as I expected. Are you running a 64 bit process on Windows? In any case your C# code implied by value, and the C++ code by ref. So that is a mismatch. You should change the C# to pass by ref explicitly.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I was busy with another task. Yes, i'm running a 64 bit process. Passing by ref worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [David Heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57490976/net-core-on-linux-marshal-structures#comment101488162_57490976) in the comments, I added an explicit `ref` keyword and it worked.

Here's my function's signature before:

```
public static extern bool ProcessInput(Settings settings, out Result result);
```

and after:

```
public static extern bool ProcessInput(ref Settings settings, out Result result);
```